# How to seperate Python Intepreter from Web Server in Django

Tags: python, django

Im making an app in django that contains a part tha does heavy calculations .I was wondering if i could execute the python code on a machine, then send the results on another machine that will run the webserver and django eachself .Can it be done ?if so please give some information on how i could do that .I want to make this happen because the system will crash if I make the calculations and serve the django application under the same machine .

Comment: There is celery (and some similar solutions) for this purpose.

Comment: Django Channels(https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or Celery(http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/django-celery/en/2.4/introduction.html) can help you.